# Indexing the dom elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, recursion, tree

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in javascript/jquery (recursive) which walks through the DOM and returns me the index of every HTML element, including parents,siblings and children. and then draws a tree of the DOM.
I need to index every element by adding an index attr to the element with the index as a string. for example:

```
<html>
<...>
<body>
<div index="1">
<div index="1.1">
<h2 index = "1.1.1">some text1</h2>
<h2 index = "1.1.2">some text</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div index="2">
<table index="2.1">
<tr index="2.1.1">
<td index="2.1.1.1">some cell</td>
<td> index = "2.1.1.2">some cell</td>
</tr>
<tr index="2.1.2">
<td index="2.1.2.1">some cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div index="3">
<h1 index="3.1">some text</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what is the best way to achieve that? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a simple iteration you can achieve this

```
function loop(el, isChild){
  for(var i=0; i<el.children.length;i++){
    var child = el.children[i];
    child.index = (isChild?(el.index + '.'):'') + (i+1);
    loop(child,false);
  }
}

loop(document.body);
```